# How to retrieve content for ids from redis sets

Tags: database, tags, nosql, redis

I'm trying to figure out what the most appropriate way to retrieve content (either a hash or string) from a set of ids.

The redis documentation talks about a tagging system [here](http://www.rediscookbook.org/implement_tags_and_search_them.html) in which sets are used to filter down books, but does not mention how you would then get information about a book. You could obviously use mget() with a list of ids once you've filtered down the the ids, but this only really works if you're working with String values and not hashes. It also means that you need to return the ids back to your application code and convert "id" to "book:id". Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Well there are many approaches you can take, Use MGET as suggested by you. What I do Generally use SORT function ... Assume we have 3 hashes like below and 1 set containing ids of those SETS

```
 HMSET 1 fname a lname b
 HMSET 2 fname c lname d
 HMSET 3 fname e lname f

 SADD fetch_from_set 1
 SADD fetch_from_set 2
 SADD fetch_from_set 3

 SORT fetch_from_set BY NOSORT GET *->fname GET *->lname

 1) "a"
 2) "b"
 3) "c"
 4) "d"
 5) "e"
 6) "f"
```

So by using this you will get the values of fname and lname. As you are using NOSORT which which will not sort the SET it should not hamper performance much.

Also, with redis 2.8 you have scan command. I have not used it but you may want to look at it.